# In php strom, I want to add command php aritsan serve system cannot find the file specified

Tags: laravel-5

[image]

> php artisan serve Cannot run program "php" (in directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\eagleeye"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings->command line tool support : remove or disable command))